# I need to get Facebook photo stream into my application using their Facebook id javascript

Tags: javascript

I am developing a web page default in an mvc application .I need to get Facebook photo stream into my application using their Facebook id. I am unable to get suitable solution.Please help me the complete solution for the same .i am using c#

Comment: Please let us know what you've tried, ideas and code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example should help you.

https://graph.facebook.com/JaramSieBrunetkami/photos

```
https://graph.facebook.com/FACEBOOK_PAGE_ID/photos
```

Comment: Thanks a ton Dawid but when i use the same with my pageid it show for token access and how can i got token for that

Comment: Write here your facebook id.